# Reading multiple UDP messages without polling

Tags: c, linux, sockets, multicast, recvmmsg

I would like to use the `recvmmsg` call to read multiple UDP messages from ONE single socket at once. I'm reading data from a single multicast group.

When I read TCP data,  I usually use `poll/select`  with a non-blocking socket (and timeout)  to be notified when that is ready to be read. I follow this approach as I am aware of the issue of spurious wakeup and potential troubles of having a blocking socket.

As my application must be very quick, if I follow the same approach with `recvmmsg` I will introduce an extra system call (`poll/select`) that might slow down the execution.

So my two questions are the following:

1. With UDP, can I safely read from BLOCKING sockets using `recvmmsg` without `poll/select` or do I have to apply the same principle I've used for TCP (non-blocking+poll)?
2. Suppose I have a huge amount of multicast traffic, would you go for non-blocking socket + `recvmmsg` only (no poll) and burn a lot of CPU?

I am using Linux: CentOS 7 and Oracle Linux.

Comment: Note that whether you use poll/select + nonblocking sockets would depend on whether you need to handle several sockets or reading/writing concurrently, not whether you're using TCP or UDP.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use blocking mode, with both TCP and UDP sockets.

If you want to impose a read timeout there is `setsockopt()` with the `SO_RCVTIMEO` option.

> I follow this approach as I am aware of the issue of spurious wakeup

**What** spurious wakeup? Never seen it in 25 years of network programming.

> and potential troubles of having a blocking socket.

Never heard of those either.

Using `select()` and non-blocking mode with a single socket is pointless unless your platform doesn't support `SO_RCVTIMEO`. It's an extra system call, for a start.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I forgot about it and you are right!! What about the performance? I might be wrong but I read somewhere that this setting is not advisable (can't remember where I did read it..I'll search for it)

Comment: Never heard that in 20+ years of network programming.

Comment: @EJP - FUD.  'blocking' sounds bad, so it must be bad.

Comment: @MartinJames Yeah, two system calls must be better than one :-|

Answer (score 0):

The option of using blocking or non-blocking depends on what is the final purpose of the application. 
- Say it's just a sample chat application showing the usage of UDP combined with TCP then you can use either. 
- But if you are planning to make this module a part of highly used application with lots of data flowing then probably creating multiple threads/processes to handle different tasks will come in handy. The parent thread will to wait for the message but for processing it will spawn a different child thread and hence make the parent available for the next message.

But in a nutshell I don't see any issue with your first option of using a blocking socket without `poll/select` for a UDP application considering it's just for homework purposes.